# How to disabled FF/RW key at List and Grid Nodes?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I used all Components like PosterGrid, ZoomRowList and TimeGrid. But, every Component Automatic Scroll using FF/RW key. I need to Stop Scrolling with that Component. I found specific Field at Rowlist which is **fadeFocusFeedbackWhenAutoScrolling**. There is a specific field for otherComponent? I also applied the below code :

```
if key = "fastforward" or key = "rewind" then //also I tried with "and" keyword
    return
end if
```

But no luck. Does anyone know How can I stop Scrolling keys inside a List and Grid Nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explicitly return `true` in that case.

```
if key = "fastforward" or key = "rewind" then
    return true
end if
```

This will let the component know that those keys have already been handled, and prevent its default behaviour.